# Number of possible riders in UberPOOL

Tags: uber-api

Am I able to set the maximum number of possible UberPOOL riders in a vehicle to something higher than 4 or 6? I'm working on a request-based shuttle program and would like to see if I could make use of the UberPOOL API for this project. Ideally I would like to bump up the number of riders in a vehicle to something much higher, probably around 10 - 15 per shuttle.

Answer (score 0):

According to the api documentation for v1.2. The max seat allowed for a uberpool is is 2. So you will not be able to request more than that. The best alternative is use uberx and XL for your request api call. However the max for UberXL is 6 occupants and the for uberx is 4 occupants.